# Books on multi-linear algebra for CS students

Tags: reference-request

I was wondering if anybody had any good recommendations on books on multi-linear algebra for graduate and ~applied computer science students.

More specifically, I am looking for reference texts that are hopefully comprehensive but that focus more on insight and applications than on providing a rigorous formal exposition of the topic.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of multi-linear algebra? I have a good one (advanced linear algebra by roman from springer) but it focuses on modules over rings.